# How can I do more complex loops in my Scriban templates?

Tags: scriban

I can loop through children like this:

```
{{ for i_child in i_datasource.children}}
```

But what if I only want the first 2, or if I want to skip the first 2 and take the next 3? Is this possible in scriban?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there are options to create loops like this in scriban:

#### The `offset` parameter

This is the scriban equivalent of `.Skip()` in .net. It allows you to start the iteration of the loop by skipping the number of entries specified:

```
{{~ for i_child in i_datasource.children offset:2 ~}}
    // display something
{{~ end ~ }}
```

#### The `limit` parameter

This is the scriban equivalent of `.Take()` in .net. It limits the number of items iterated through in the loop.

```
{{~ for i_child in i_datasource.children limit:2 ~}}
    // display something
{{~ end ~ }}
```

You can also use these together:

```
{{~ for i_child in i_datasource.children offset: 2 limit:4 ~}}
    // display something
{{~ end ~ }}
```

Scriban loop language reference: https://github.com/scriban/scriban/blob/master/doc/language.md#95-loops